# releasing a strong property

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to know how to release a strong property. I would like to clarify why I intend to do this. I own an object via this property declaration:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  __strong MyObject *myHeavyObject;
}
@end
```

I create this object in some method, I use it in another, so on and so forth.

```
- (void)someMethod {
  myHeavyObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
  ...
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
  id response = [myHeavyObject getResponse];
}
```

At some point however, i KNOW i no longer need it, and since it is heavy, I would like to get rid of it:

```
- (void)someCallDidFinish {
  //i no longer need myHeavyObject...how do I get rid of it?
}
```

I don't want to wait till dealloc since that could be a long time. I know I don't use this object any more, so how can I make it go away? How is this supported in the ARC paradigm? Is this something reasonable to ask for?

Ying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set it to nil. The old value will be released when a new one is set.